# Tensors that describe the symmetry groups

Tags: group-theory, tensors, spherical-harmonics

In this [article](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.66.031704), Table 1 lists different symmetry groups and the tensors that describe them. However, it is unclear how the authors reached these results. They just refer to the [book](https://books.google.com.br/books?hl=en&lr=&id=xdwoAwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=group%20theory%20and%20quantum%20mechanics&ots=qe5wNC7Nfg&sig=zYPrCEPAJBiBOdjCk_hAq6oI41g#v=onepage&q=group%20theory%20and%20quantum%20mechanics&f=false), and it is unclear how they deduced the tensors relative to each symmetry group.

Could anyone explain to me the first example of the list? It says that the group $C_{\infty v}$ is described by the rank-3 tensor $T_1$ with components $T_{1}^{ijk}=\sqrt{5/2}\left[ n^in^jn^k-\frac{1}{5}\left( \delta^{ij}n^k+\delta^{jk}n^i+\delta^{ki}n^j\right)\right]$, where the unity vector $\hat{n}$ defines a rotation axis of the group $C_{\infty v}$. It presents other 6 rank-3 tensors, but why they aren't used is unclear.

**Which are the rank-3 tensors that represents the symmetry group $C_{\infty v}$?**

I know that the seven rank-3 tensors come from the multipolar expansion but my poor knowledge in general downs permit to understand everything. One of these tensors is the $T_2$ with components $T_2^{ijk}=\frac{1}{2}\left( m^im^jm^k-m^il^jl^k-m^jl^kl^i-m^kl^il^j\right)$, where $\hat{m}\times\hat{l}=\hat{n}$. The article says a third tensor $T_3$ together with $T_2$ describes the symmetry $D_{3h}$. The reason is unclear to me.

I know a bit about rank-n tensors but almost nothing about group theory. So, I'm sorry for my naive question.